# Reading from files with ':' between each variable. C++

Tags: c++

Hey so I have this text file:

```
1:Vegetarian Dishes:Lettuce:1.99
2:Vegetarian Dishes:Tomato:0.99
3:Drinks:Water:0.5
4:Meat Dishes:Burger:4.99
5:Fish Dishes:Fishes:5
6:Drinks:Coka cola:2.5
7:Drinks:Fanta:1.2
8:Drinks:Absolut:12.99
9:Drinks:Wiskey:9.99
10:Vegetarian Dishes:Lemon:0.99
11:Vegetarian Dishes:Green:2.99
12:Meat Dishes:Pizza:4.99
13:Fish Dishes:Fishes2:5.99
14:Drinks:Milk shake:4.99
15:Vegetarian Dishes:Vegan Sandwich:3.99
```

and i have objects of Dish class, so I want to read the file and add each dish to a Dish object. 
Then i have an array of Dishes. Its supposed to store _itemNo:category:description:price.

Below is my code.

The problem is that it doesn't read the file correctly. Do you see any problems?

Code:

```
Dish::Dish() {    }

Dish::Dish(int itemNo, string category, string description,
            double price): _itemNo(itemNo), _category(category),
             _description(description), _price(price) {     }

void Dish::displayDish(void){

    cout << setw(15) << left << _itemNo << setw(30) << left << _category
    << setw(45) << left << _description << _price << endl;

}



DishDb::DishDb(): _nElems(0) {    }

void DishDb::addDish(int itemNo, string category, string description,
        double price){

        _menu[_nElems] = Dish(itemNo, category, description, price);
        _nElems++;

    }
void DishDb::display(){

    int i;

    cout <<setw(40) << "MENU" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Item No" << setw(15) << "Category" << setw(30)
    << "Description" << setw(40)<< "Price" << endl << endl;

    for(i = 0; i < _nElems; i++){   
        _menu[i].displayDish();

    }


}

int main(){

    /*Select file name for the bills to be stored in*/
    string transFilename;

    cout << "Enter today's transaction file name: ";

    cin >> transFilename;


    /*Load the menu*/
    /*Adding each dish object into the _nenu array*/
    /*Couldn't make this part object oriented*/

    DishDb ddb;
    string fileName;
    int itemNo;
    double price;
    string description;
    string category;

    int i;

    int numOfDishes = 0;

    cout << "Enter file name: ";

    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream inFile(fileName);

    while(i<15){

        inFile >> itemNo;

        getline(inFile, category, ':');

        getline(inFile, description, ':');

        inFile >> price;

        numOfDishes++;

        Dish(itemNo, category, description, price);

        ddb.addDish(itemNo, category, description, price);
        i++;


    }

    ddb.display();
    inFile.close();

/*  while(inFile >> itemNo && getline(inFile, category, ':') &&
          getline(inFile, description, ':') && inFile >> price){


        numOfDishes++;

        Dish(itemNo, category, description, price);

        ddb.addDish(itemNo, category, description, price);


    }
    */
    cout << endl << "Menu was loaded."; 




    return 0;
}


I've tried 2 ways of reading the file. With the first i was just checking if the file was beging read correctly but its not.
```

Comment: Can't debug your code for you but see this:  https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/21/how-to-split-a-string-in-c/  *(it's actually about C++)*

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work for you:

```
int main() {
  std::ifstream file("dishes.txt");
  std::string temp, snum, category, description, sprice;
  while (std::getline(file, snum, ':') &&
         std::getline(file, category, ':') &&
         std::getline(file, description, ':') &&
         std::getline(file, sprice)) {
    // Do whatever you want with:
    // * snum (must convert to integer)
    // * category
    // * description
    // * sprice (must convert to float)
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest having the outer loop call `std::getline()` without a delimiter to read an entire line into a `std::string`, then use a `std::istringstream` to parse the line using `std::getline()` with a delimiter.

Comment: That makes sense, it may make it less prone to errors. Anyway, I am not a huge fan of using stringstream to split strings (don't ask why), even knowing it has the advantage of converting to different data types, I rather use boost::tokenizer and cast the items myself.